# change image format using Imagick()

Tags: php, imagemagick

I want to change image file as jpeg format as follows:

```
$img_real_path = realpath(".") . "/" .$dest;
echo $img_real_path;
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage($img_real_path);
$image->setImageFormat("jpeg");
```

But image format is same as it was. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using `$image->imageWriteFile()`

Add this to your code:

```
$image->imageWriteFile (fopen ($image_real_path, "wb"));
```

It should look like this:

```
$img_real_path = realpath(".") . "/" .$dest;
echo $img_real_path;
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage($img_real_path);
$image->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$image->imageWriteFile (fopen ($image_real_path, "wb"));
```

Comment: Thanks. what does it mean by "wb"? which opening mode does it represent?

Comment: It means write (w) in binary (b).

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Imagick::imageWriteFile() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bim\bim_2014\sites\default\modules\bim_apps\bim_apps.module on line 2108

Comment: Try this instead: `file_put_contents ('NEW_IMAGE_NAME.jpg', $image);`

Comment: Did it fix the problem for you?